# UITableView cells disappear on selection (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have been looking all over stackoverflow but haven't found a solution yet, despite many questions with a similar title.

I have two `UITableView` within a single `UIViewController` and two custom `UITableViewController` classes to serve as Delegate and Data Source for these two tables. I managed to get the data populated in the table but all the cells disappear right after I select a row. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class SearchFiltersViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var typeTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var regionTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Setup filter and region table
        let typeDataSourceAndDelegate = TypeDataSourceAndDelegate()
        typeDataSourceAndDelegate.view = self.typeTable

        self.typeTable.dataSource = typeDataSourceAndDelegate
        self.typeTable.delegate = typeDataSourceAndDelegate

        self.typeTable.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

class TypeDataSourceAndDelegate: UITableViewController {
    let CELL_IDENTIFIER = "customTypeCell"

    var allTypes = [CustomType]()

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if self.allTypes.count == 0 {
            self.resetTypes()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.CELL_IDENTIFIER, forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let type = self.allTypes[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = type.title

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.allTypes.count
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        selectedCell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.hrColors().lightGreyColor()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        selectedCell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.hrColors().whiteColor()
    }

    func resetTypes() {
        self.allTypes = [CustomType(id: 0, title: "All Types")]
    }
}
```

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` methods are not even being called. Help?

Comment: I wouldn't use a subclass of UITableViewController as delegate and data source if the view is manages by a view controller. I would just use a subclass of NSObject. Maybe this also solves your problem.

Comment: If I do that, the method 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' never gets called and the table is never populated.

Comment: You need to set the data source and the delegate in the Interface Builder.

Comment: Despite that, 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' doesn't get called. `numberOfRowsInSection` does get called but nothing else. Give it a try. You can't add delegate or data source using the interface builder if its a custom class and not the controller (I think, please correct me if i am wrong). I had then programatically.

Comment: I do this all the time. I'm sure you can do that.

Comment: please, visit this link for detail answer. this may help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38589010/2797847